# One time login on 2 different Wordpress sites

Tags: login, cookies, session

Im trying to figure out how to login one time to mydomain.com and being automatically loged in to mydomain.com/blog . 
I have figured out how to share tables (so that the same users on my main site, are also on the blog site) through MyPHPAdmin. 
I was hoping in this manner, I wouldn't have to use WPMU. Any advice, or links would be GREATLY appreciated. 
Im currently using version 3.8.1

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your goal is. It sounds more like automatic logging in into the database, rather than into the WordPress installation.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't sound specific. Im not really sure how to word it. I would like to login as (example admin) on BOTH dashboards as a one time login.
Would this be called "cross installation"

Comment: A Multisite installation only has one (shared) user table per default.

Comment: yes, I successfully did that through this method
http://mikemclin.net/single-users-table-multiple-wordpress-sites/

Comment: Normally you can register users to as many of your subsites as you want. You can alter the settings responsible for if an admin needs to confirm the new user, etc. So if I got you right, then this is already built in and you just have to tweak your settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my own experience to this thread. I've tried many different configurations of WordPress cookie constants in wp-config without any luck. I'm setup in the same way as described by the OP using custom_user_table and meta_table.

I've found the session information does actually translate across different pages if you use `COOKIE_DOMAIN` as another answer suggested (in my case domain.com and domain.com/support) - and the session data is there but WordPress still doesn't log you in. I'm still looking into the issue. I also found I needed to define the `COOKIEHASH` constant for the session data to match.

`define('COOKIEHASH', md5( 'domain.com') );`

You also need to make sure the salts in wp-config are identical.

Also a note to other folks that might have a similar issue - you need to set and manage user capabilities for the 2nd installation and that info is stored in the 2nd installs user meta table (even though you explicity set a different custom user meta table pointing to the primary install).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate WP sites and both have access to the same database, you can have one instance use the other instance's user tables by editing your wp-config.php.  Since they are both the same domain, you can configure your cookie domain:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE','firstsite_user_table');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'firstsite_usermeta_table');

define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'mydomain.com' );
```

Note: This configuration works like single sign-on (SSO) only when the sites use the same domain.  This will not work if sites are on different domains.

Edited to add COOKIE_DOMAIN setting.

Comment: The asker explicitly stated that he has this part working, but needs login to work cross-installation.

Comment: Would I need to add that on BOTH wp-configs or just the main one (which happens to be mydomain.com) ?

Comment: How did you configure both instances to use the same tables?  You should have configured CUSTOM_USER_TABLE and CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE in your second site; assuming that the second site has access to the same database as the first site.  If you did it another way then all this might not work.  The COOKIE_DOMAIN should be configured on both sites.

Comment: I used this method http://mikemclin.net/single-users-table-multiple-wordpress-sites/, will it work?

Comment: @Ebizl How about trying it?

Comment: Did it, but now when I try to log back in, I get ERROR: Invalid username. Tried to put it in both wp.config, then the main one as well.
And when I try to register a new user name (with the codes now on both WP configs) I get 
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/mydomain/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 655

Comment: Ebizl - Since you already configured CUSTOM_USER_TABLE and CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE.  You only need to add the COOKIE_DOMAIN to both site's wp-config.php.

Comment: yes, and its giving me an invalid username.

Comment: Addiing/changing cookie domain should not be giving you invalid username.  You must be making multiple changes.  Undo the COOKIE_DOMAIN and see if you can login.

Comment: yes, i can login when i remove the cookie domain. Say, I noticed when I noticed, I have this already on one of the wp-config

Comment: i have this from when I was configuring a user table

define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'mytable_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'mytable_usermeta');

is it the same as the one you sent me earlier?

define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE','mytable_user_table');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'mytable_usermeta_table');
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'mydomain.com' );

Comment: Ebizl - The settings I used above are pseudo-names, You need to replace with your own table names and (cookie) domain.

Comment: I thought I did, [ firstsite ], right? I replace it with my main site's table, right?